# If $\cos3A + \cos3B + \cos3C = 1$ in a triangle, find one of its length

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I would like to solve the following problem.

> In $\triangle ABC, AC = 10, BC = 13$. If $\cos3A + \cos3B + \cos3C = 1$, compute the length of $AB$.

I thought that I could apply the Law of Cosines. Using the fact that $A+B+C=\pi$, I attempted to build the equation up from there.

What I got was that $$\cos3A+\cos3B-\cos(3A+3B)=1$$

Expanding, I got $$\cos3A+\cos3B-\cos3A\cos3B-\sin3A\sin3B=1$$

Now, it's possible that I'd be able to factor it somehow by rewriting it all in terms of cosine and arrive at the answer, but is there a better way to solve the problem? Thanks!

Comment: You can accept any answer you like which satisfies the requirements of the question instead of keeping the question marked as unanswered. If you think none of the answer meets the requirements then you can share a bounty to attract more attention from people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\mathbf {Hint...}$

$$\cos {3A}+\cos {3B}+ \cos{3C}=1$$
$$\Rightarrow 4 \sin {\frac {3C}{2}} .\sin {\frac{3B}{2}} .\sin{\frac{3A}{2}}=0$$

Hence the largest angle of triangle is $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ which can be either angle $C$ or angle $A$. By applying cosine rule in each of these cases we get the value of $AB$ as $\sqrt {399}$ or $\sqrt {94}-5$ respectively.

Note:

$$\cos {3A}+\cos {3B}+ \cos{3C}=1$$
$$\Rightarrow -2\cos {\frac {3(A-B)}{2}}\sin {\frac {3C}{2}}- 2\left(\sin  {\frac {3C}{2}}\right)^2=0$$

$$=\sin\frac{3C}{2}\left(\cos\frac{3(A-B)}{2}+ \sin\frac{3C}{2}\right)=0$$

$$\sin\frac{3C}{2}\left(\cos\frac{3(A-B)}{2}-\cos\frac{3(A+B)}{2}\right)=0$$

$$\sin\frac{3C}{2}\sin\frac{3B}{2}\sin\frac{3A}{2}=0.$$

Comment: How did you get the second equation?

Answer (score 1):

We have $$2\cos\frac{3A+3B}{2}\cos\frac{3A-3B}{2}-2\sin^2\frac{3C}{2}=0$$ or
$$\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}-\frac{3C}{2}\right)\cos\frac{3A-3B}{2}-\sin^2\frac{3C}{2}=0$$ or
$$\sin\frac{3C}{2}\left(-\cos\frac{3A-3B}{2}-\sin\frac{3C}{2}\right)=0$$ or
$$\sin\frac{3C}{2}\left(-\cos\frac{3A-3B}{2}+\cos\frac{3A+3B}{2}\right)=0$$ or
$$\sin\frac{3C}{2}\sin\frac{3C}{2}\sin\frac{3C}{2}=0$$ or
$$\prod_{cyc}\left(3\sin\frac{A}{2}-4\sin^3\frac{A}{2}\right)=0$$ or
$$\prod_{cyc}\left(3-4\sin^2\frac{A}{2}\right)=0$$ or
$$\prod_{cyc}\left(3-2(1-\cos{A})\right)=0$$ or
$$\prod_{cyc}\left(1+\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{bc}\right)=0$$ or
$$\prod_{cyc}(b^2+c^2+ab-a^2)=0.$$
Can you end now?

Answer (score 0):

Using the identity
\begin{align} 
\cos3\alpha+\cos3\beta+\cos3\gamma
&=
1-\frac{r\,(3\,\rho^2-(r+3\,R)^2)}{R^3}
\tag{1}\label{1}
,
\end{align}
where $r$ is the inradius, $R$ is the circumradius
and $\rho$ is the semiperimeter 
of the triangle, 
condition 
\begin{align} 
\cos3\alpha+\cos3\beta+\cos3\gamma&=1
\end{align}

results in

\begin{align} 
3\,\rho^2-(r+3\,R)^2&=0
,\\
3\,\rho^2-\left(\frac{S}{\rho}+3\,\frac{abc}{4S}\right)^2&=0
,\\
3\,\rho^2
-\frac{S^2}{\rho^2}
-\frac{3abc}{2\rho}
-\tfrac{9}{16}\frac{(abc)^2}{S^2}&=0
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\\
\end{align}
where $S$ is the area of triangle.
With the help of substitution
\begin{align}
\rho&=\tfrac12(a+b+c)
,\\
S^2&=\tfrac1{16}(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)
,\\
a&=13
,\quad
b=10
\end{align}

equation \eqref{2} becomes

\begin{align}
\frac{(c^2-399)(c^2+13c+69)(c^2+10c-69)}{(c^2-9)(c^2-23^2)}
&=0
,
\end{align}

with just two suitable roots,
\begin{align}
c_1&=\sqrt{399}
,\\
c_2&=\sqrt{94}-5
.
\end{align}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos {3A}+\cos {3B}+ \cos{3C}=1$$
$$\Rightarrow 4 \sin {\frac {3C}{2}} .\sin {\frac{3B}{2}} .\sin{\frac{3A}{2}}=0$$

Hence the largest angle of triangle is $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ which can be either angle $C$ or angle $A$. By applying cosine rule in each of these cases we get the value of $AB$ as $\sqrt {399}$ or $\sqrt {94}-5$ respectively.