# In a triangle $ABC$, $\cos 3A + \cos 3B + \cos 3C = 1$, then find any one angle.

Tags: trigonometry

> In a triangle $ABC$, $\cos 3A + \cos 3B + \cos 3C = 1$, then find any one angle.
>
> **HINT**: The answer is **$\frac{2\pi}{8}$**

I have tried these steps and got stuck in the middle.
$$ A +B + C = \pi$$
$$ A + B = \pi - C$$
$$\cos 3A + \cos 3B + \cos 3C = 1 \longrightarrow$$
$$2\cos{\frac{3A + 3B}{2}}\cos{\frac{3A - 3B}{2}} + \cos 3C = 1$$
$$2\cos{\frac{3A + 3B}{2}}\cos{\frac{3A - 3B}{2}} + \cos{(\frac{3\pi}{2}-\frac{3A - 3B}{2})} = 1  \text{  [since $A - B = \pi -C$]  } $$
$$2\cos{\frac{3A + 3B}{2}}\cos{\frac{3A - 3B}{2}} - \sin{\frac{3A + 3B}{2}} = 1$$

From here onwards I do not know how to continue. Please check if my method is correct and help me solve the problem. Thanks :)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2597796/if-cos3a-cos3b-cos3c-1-in-a-triangle-find-one-of-its-length/2597809

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $$\cos 3A+\cos3B+\cos3C=1$$
$$\implies\sum\cos3A=1$$
$$\implies\sin\dfrac{3A}{2}\cdot\sin\dfrac{3B}{2}\cdot\sin\dfrac{3C}{2}=0$$

Therefore,$$A=\dfrac{2\pi}{3}\mbox{ or }B=\dfrac{2\pi}{3}\mbox{ or }C=\dfrac{2\pi}{3}$$

Comment: Thanks for your help. But your answer is wrong

Comment: @Rash How is my answer wrong?

Comment: The source that I copied this question from, says that the answer is $\frac{2\pi}{8}$

Comment: @Rash It could be a typo

Comment: I think that @KeyFlex is correct after looking at the working.

Comment: And yah @kyky it could have been a typo

Comment: @KeyFlex Why did you reject my edit

Comment: @Rash I didn't reject your edit. It might be rejected by others when they reviewed your edit